# VBA Bloomberg (BDH) formula for data extraction

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I have an issue running the Bloomberg BDH formula via VBA code.

The formula in the code works perfectly when executed in the Excel worksheet in a formula format (typing the formula in the cell)

but when I place the formula in the VBA code and retype it accordingly, I get an error which I can not figure out.

this is the formula executed in the cell (which works like this):

```
=BDH("CNC US Equity","Best_Ask,Best_Bid,Trade","2019-02-06 09:00:00","2019-02-07 22:00:00","Dir=V","IntrRw=true","CondCodes=S","QRM=S","Spread=S","ExchCode=S","Dts=S")
```

In the VBA `BDH formula`, via the `InputSheet` I am referencing a stock eg `CNC US Equity`, the needed parameters `Best_Ask,Best_Bid,Trade` and the `dates`.

the formula is supposed to be pasted in multiple cells on multiple sheets referencing in each instance a different `equity` and a different `date range`

this is where I have an issue the code wont even paste the formula in the cell, I have triple checked every value which is being referenced in the formula, but everything seems to be correct, I even ran a test excel formula `Worksheets(Exportsheet1).Cells(1, z).Value = "=SQRT(4)"` to see if there is any issue in the code but found nothing.

```
 Dim name1(423) As Variant
 Dim out2(33, 17) As Variant
 Dim A As Variant
 Dim B As Variant
 Dim C As Variant
 Dim B1 As Variant
 Dim B2 As Variant
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim z As Integer
 Dim t As Integer
 Dim w As Integer


 Const InputSheet = "DATA"
 Const InputRange = "D2:AB424"
 Const nameRange = "C2:C424"
 Const Exportsheet1 = "Tempo1"
 Const Exportsheet2 = "Tempo2"
 Const Exportsheet3 = "Tempo3"
 Const Exportsheet4 = "Tempo4"
 Const Exportrange1 = "A1:AX34"


 Sheets(InputSheet).Activate

 z = 1
 For x = 1 To 100
    For y = 2 To 26
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, y).Value) = False Then
            'Worksheets(Exportsheet1).Cells(1, z).Value = "=SQRT(4)"
            Worksheets(Exportsheet1).Cells(1, z).Value = "=BDH(WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, 1).Value;WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(424, 1).Value;""""WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, y).Value - 1)"""";""""WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, 1).Value"""";""""Dir=V"""";""""IntrRw=true"""";""""CondCodes=S"""";""""QRM=S"""";""""Spread=S"""";""""ExchCode=S"""";""""Dts=S"""")"

            z = z + 1

        End If
    Next y
 Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `,` instead of `;` in your formula

Comment: Doesn't work with ```,```, throws a formula error, that's why I use ```;``` could have something to do with Bloomberg API

Comment: Did you try with `.formula` instead of `.value` ?

Comment: You're missing several "" it should be `"=BDH("&WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, 1).Value&";"&WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(424, 1).Value .......` every cell reference of your VBA needs to be outside the "..."

Comment: Try: `Worksheets(Exportsheet1).Cells(1, z).Value = "=BDH(WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, 1).Value"""";""""WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(424, 1).Value"""";""""WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, y).Value - 1)"""";""""WorkSheets(InputSheet).Cells(x, 1).Value"""";""""Dir=V"""";""""IntrRw=true"""";""""CondCodes=S"""";""""QRM=S"""";""""Spread=S"""";""""ExchCode=S"""";""""Dts=S"""")"`